# WSO2 APIM 4.0.0 SSO with keycloak oidc logout fail

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I had deployed *WSO2 APIM 4.0.0* in my VM and configured SSO with keycloak oidc.

Login works fine, but Logout fails for redirecting too many times in browser.

Logout operation works fine sometimes, but most times fails.

I don't know why.

Here is the URL when logout from browser:

```
https://keycloak.okd.cestc.com.cn:8443/auth/realms/registry/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ4QjMyUy1JdkFfaWN1U0dsNlMtNXlVNm9CUkc2ODM0VE9jd3VvbVV4NVVnIn0.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.F1_cxuU0TOl2tSrjEbwGcpyyha3iLBGyKGucp3od06P7HC7JslCdmeM5lwCHx2BKbxLByzG7ZcMeA6F6J3hMEKvXzxkZKQkHqy0jGeQdM7mmZFJsAjfxMpPxXN9KPS3C8Aw9RgyZlwKBBANNgU6Ur2SMiTVOwGtWUvrcGBnd_mry2-CGslqVUVeAl-RMSkJ0b8KiAIQowaEDWqyr5kejAnIa7w6dVz6PzTd8GBaAcwtOLhX7heNId0fhwLgC9Mxth_pRMeDz3MVafaxbjpttkyPacj1lgoE6pPMD-eu0wRdUmlyzHGD3iIVDeIsuEl6Qbnzbq940Q8b8qj4NjM9-8g&state=dc9ff587-bb56-4968-8c80-0e968ff6e440%2COIDC&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fregistry.okd.cestc.com.cn%3A9443%2Fcommonauth
```

Comment: Please add more information over how did you configure keycloak realm and how did you configure the Keycloak Identity Provider in WSO2 APIM.